Вывод значения, с колеса фортуны
На днях нашел в Гугле интересную тему, колесо фортуны ссылка (https://thecode.media/fortune/amp/)
Помоги дописать скрипт так чтобы после вращения выпавшее значение показалось на экране так, чтобы можно было на него нажать, либо само слово будет линком(пустым #) либо будет рядом какая нибудь кнопка по типу claim now
